# Excel 2019 - Automatic insert time on a cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've already found article about how to automatically add date on a cell. I used it and change it to add time on a cell (Code below).

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Range("D:D"), Target)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
rng1.Offset(0, -2).Value = Time()
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Question is:
How can I change code to do the same in the same sheet but in different column?

Now I entering data on column "D" and get time on column "B". I want also enter data in column "K" and get time on column "I"

Unfortunately I'm not good in coding and I don't have any idea how correctly edit this code.

I also forgot to tell that I want to use this macro on excel placed on Sharepoint website.

Can I ask you guys for help??

Best regards Christof

Comment: `Unfortunately I'm not good in coding and I don't have any idea how correctly edit this code.` I can give you the code but I want you to try it first. Read up on how `.Offset` works :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the offset D to B and K to I is -2 in both cases you can use

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Or Target.Column = 11 Then ' D or K
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(0, -2).Value = Time()
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Code work perfectly and think that this code is more clear to me then previous one. Thank you.